# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](http://japanese.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What's the difference between 水 and 湯](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21526/whats-the-difference-between-%e6%b0%b4-and-%e6%b9%af)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Placing a quantifier between a noun and particle?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/placing-a-quantifier-between-a-noun-and-particle)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [いい人そう。using "seemingly" そう with nouns?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21836/%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86-using-seemingly-%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86-with-nouns)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [自意識過剰 - what does it mean, exactly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21823/%e8%87%aa%e6%84%8f%e8%ad%98%e9%81%8e%e5%89%b0-what-does-it-mean-exactly)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Usage of an adjective 細やか（な）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21732/usage-of-an-adjective-%e7%b4%b0%e3%82%84%e3%81%8b-%e3%81%aa)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Use of 「～ておりますしょうか。 」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/use-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8a%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Nuance and current-ness of "ぼくとお茶しませんか"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21801/nuance-and-current-ness-of-%e3%81%bc%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8a%e8%8c%b6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93%e3%81%8b)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What's the meaning of と in 「『・・・・・・』っていう文章だと良かった」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21393/whats-the-meaning-of-%e3%81%a8-in-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e6%96%87%e7%ab%a0%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a8%e8%89%af%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Passive vs Active form of verbs when used as adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/passive-vs-active-form-of-verbs-when-used-as-adjectives)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [The usage of 侮れなかった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21361/the-usage-of-%e4%be%ae%e3%82%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 7)

---